# Error in callback for watcher, Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I am using this [mixin](https://github.com/BKWLD/vue-in-viewport-mixin) - But it gives me an error in IE11, not in Chrome, FF, Safari, so it seems it's only a IE related issue..

The error im getting is: **Error in callback for watcher "inViewport.now": "TypeError: Object doesn't support this action"** (WAT?)

The watcher code looks like:

```
watch: {
  'inViewport.now': function(visible) {
    if(visible) {
      this.loadDataToSystem();
      this.elementIsVisible = true;

      //Update graph with new data
      this.resetTimer();
      this.updateGraphOptions.minutes = updateIn;

      this.updateGraphDataTimer = setInterval(function () {
        this.loadDataToSystem();
      }.bind(this), 300000);

    } else {
      this.elementIsVisible = false;
      //Stop updating graph
      this.stopTimer();
      clearInterval(this.updateGraphDataTimer);
      this.updateGraphOptions.minutes = null;
      this.updateGraphOptions.started = false;
    }
  }
},
```

Do anyone have an idea on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It wasn't the plugin that failed, but this that failed in IE11:

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('scroll'));